# Explode checkbox input value in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

So i have input checkbox code like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='cek[]' class='check1' value='$data[id_usulan]' >
```

And there is an input text with id = test2, so when i click the checkbox, the input text value will change to checkbox value (there's no problem with this), i use this javascript code to do it:

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
        var sum=0;
        if ($("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked')) {
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(index){
            sum += Number($(this).val().replace( /[^\d.]/g,''));
        });
            }
        $("#test2").val(sum);
    } );
```

And then i change the checkbox:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='cek[]' class='check1' value='$data[id_usulan]/$data[jml_harga]' >
```

As you can see, i tried to use 2 value in one checkbox (`$data[id_usulan]` and `$data[jml_harga]`, separated by '`/`' ), but i just want to use one value (`$data[jml_harga]`) for `$(this).val()`, well you might think that if i want to use `$data[jml_harga]` then i don't have to make 2 value, but don't ask that, there's another reason for why i use 2 value.

So this is what I have tried:

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    var sum=0;
    if ($("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked')) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(index){
     var explode = $(this).val().split('/');
     var price = explode[2];
        sum += Number(price.replace( /[^\d.]/g,''));
    });
        }
    $("#test2").val(sum);
} );
```

But when i click the checkbox, the input text value didn't change to checkbox value and remains the same as before I check, so how to fix this problem?

If anyone has a way to solve this, please help me.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:
`var price = explode[2];`

The second value is:
`var price = explode[1];`

Comment: ohh it's so embarrassing, that the answer really simple, since i only use explode now, i really didn't has any idea.. -_-
well, thank You very much, you helped me.. :D